# Array.Contains() throws index out of range exception

Tags: c#, arrays

I don't understand how can such a line throw and index out of range exception (sorry for the French exception). Array.Contains() should return wether it's found or not, it should be simple. The array is not null.

See the image to illustrate the situation.[image]

Comment: You should use a `List<T>` instead of an array.

Comment: @SLaks It's generated by a third party, so unfortunatly I have no choice here. I agree that we should use List<T> as often as possible!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception is actually from the previous line.
If you unwind the stack, the highlight should be corrected.

Arrays go from `0` to `Count - 1`; `fields[fields.Count()]` is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Exception is thrown by line above.

```
fields[fields.Count()] =..
```

it should be

```
fields[fields.Count() - 1] =..
```